# jQuery load() whole html file but only show single divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load the whole html content of an extern html file from the server into my website - just like a php inculde would do more or less.

So far I can load the whole file and show in a div while using the id and all.

But how can I only show one part of the div?

This is my HTML with the jQuery Script:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta title="TITLE">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#main").load('file.html');
      });
    </script>
    <style></style>     
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="main">
      <div id="PlaceSubNaviOne"></div>
      <div id="PlaceSubNaviTwo"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
```

This is the content of the HTML file i want to load from:

```
<div id="subnavione">
  <ul>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
    <li>CITY1</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="subnavitwo">
  <ul>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
    <li>CITY2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do now is, to only load the file once and then place the content into the specific divs I placed on my Website. For Example, I want to place the div `subnavione` from `file.html` into the div `PlaceSubNaviOne` and the same for the `subnavitwo` and `PlaceSubnaviTwo`.

Is this possible with jQuery `load()` or do i have to use a different way to get this done?

Comment: "Is this possible with jQuery load()?" Did you try it to find out?

Comment: i already managed to do it with load() in first place. But the problem is that i have to store the html i got from the load() into a div from which i can then place the specific html in single divs. my question was to load the html file once and just hold it in the back. then place the specific html into the single divs. thats why i asked if THIS is possible with load() or if i have to use a totaly different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$( "#main" ).load( "file.html", function() {
  $("#PlaceSubNaviOne").html($("#subnavione").html());
});
```

Refer : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: when i use this the .load() places the whole html file code into the #main div and the  $("#PlaceSubNaviOne").html($("#subnavione").html()); places the code of the subnavione div into the PlaceSubNaviOne. now i have everything double on my website

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can make use of `.get()` here as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get( "file.html", function( data ) {
      $( "#PlaceSubNaviOne" ).html( $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#subnavione") );
      $( "#PlaceSubNaviTwo" ).html( $($.parseHTML(data)).filter('#subnavitwo') );
  });
});
```

For more information on jquery **[get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**